# Program 'wsl.exe' failed to run: The file cannot be accessed by the system

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

Today after restoring windows 11 from the recent restore point (4 days ago), my wls2 setup is not working any more. Whenever I typed any WSL command from PowerShell (administrator access) it's showing below error:

[image: Click here to see screenshot]

And when I tried to start Ubuntu then it's shown below error on the windows terminal:

[image: Click here to see screenshot]

Kindly help me to find out the issue. I can reinstall the Ubuntu distro but how to solve wsl2 error?

Note: Previously it's working without any issue. I have moved Ubuntu distro and docker-desktop-data moved from primary drive (C) to another drive (D).

chkdsk command status

[click here to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzeeE.png)

Comment: What happened that required System Restore? Does `chkdsk` find any problem? Does the file `C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe` exist?

Comment: @harrymc: No issue found during chkdsk and yes wsl.exe exist in this location.

Comment: Can you launch it using its full path?

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall *Windows Subsystem on Linux*

Comment: I have already tried but no success, even tried to run directly from the window explorer

Comment: @Ramhound: that will be my last option bcoz after that I have to re-setup all my projects again

Comment: No; You wouldn’t

Comment: @Ramhound how that's possible bcoz after uninstall and then install the Linux will delete the data including settings. Also, I am not sure that after uninstalling the Linux, how wsl will work bcoz right now even if I type any wsl command, it's throw error (see above attached image for reference)

Comment: Thank you to all of you for your help and time, the issue has been resolved. After restoring the system again this issue has been resolved, not sure how but the issue is resolved.

Comment: @PushkarRana what exactly did you do to restore the settings?

Comment: @PushkarRana Can you please add an answer with how you restored the system? This issue does not appear to be affecting only you. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To restore all Windows components to a know state, I suggest to do
[Repair Install Windows 11 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/).

This operation is the same as installing a major Windows update.
It will keep all your applications and data,
but I suggest taking good backups before starting.

Comment: Initially, I tried the repair option from the advance option of troubleshooting the window. But after that, I chose the restore option bcoz the issue was not resolved (icon disappeared & screen flickering)

Comment: Try doing Repair from USB media.